# In windows operating system, where passwords are saved and in which format they are saved?

Tags: operating-system

Consider the Operating System is installed on C drive. And what is the file type used to save passwords.

Comment: What do you mean by all passwords : session windows, browser passwords, application passwords ...? all of that a storing in different way, and path.

Answer (score 3):

Windows logon passwords are never stored in their original form and always encrypted. They are stored in `C:/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/config` (Assuming windows installed in C drive) folder. Passwords are stored in files called sam files. But they are hashed and so encrypted.

For passwords other than windows passwords, their storage and encryption depend on the application that created those passwords. They might reside on your computer or on a remote location.

Comment: The "SAM" file is a registry hive, which gets loaded at "HKLM\SAM". Normally only SYSTEM can read "HKLM\SAM\SAM", but an administrator has the right to modify the security on the Key to get access. In principle, an administrator also has the right to read the underlying "SAM" file, but the system keeps it open without read or write sharing.